# Помогите понять в чем проблема, почему не срабатывает?

Tags: python

```
games = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)

games.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Денчик крутой', callback_data='pubg'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Денчик класс', callback_data='brawl'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я построил для него дворец', callback_data='standoff'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back')
    )
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\FUNTI\Desktop\piton> python bot.py
  File "bot.py", line 16
    games = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)

ошибка в консоли

Comment: Скорее всего реальная ошибка где-то строчкой выше. Скобочку не закрыли или двоеточие не поставили, например.